# prevent content from flowing when inline-block div height's grow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j2h8j4e/) to explain this issue.

```js
$(".box").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 25em;
}
.box {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.hover {
  height: 7em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

When the height of the box grows, the rest of the flowing content inside the wrapper, flows down. I want to prevent the content from flowing when the height grows, and instead, that the box overwrap the other boxes.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: You can add a [negative `margin-bottom` rule](http://jsfiddle.net/8j2h8j4e/2/) to match the increase in height. Not that this is particularly elegant.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh2wbomw/). It is a bit cumbersome, as I had to manually specify the top and left of each div but it works.

Comment: Thanks both! @malhotraprateek I need to achieve that effect, but using inline-block, when using "position:absolute" the flow breaks

Comment: By the way, why do you use JS to set `hover` class instead of `.box:hover` selector?

Answer (score 1):

You can add negative `margin-bottom` to your `hover` class.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8j2h8j4e/5/).

Also, you could wrap each row in a `div` with required `max-height`.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8j2h8j4e/4/).